# SSRS Report Viewer not setting dependent parameter on selection of parent parameter for the first time

Tags: reporting-services, report-viewer2016

In my report there are only two parameters. When I am setting the first parameter the second parameter valid values and the default values should be set automatically. This is working absolutely fine in the Report Builder.

However, in the ASP.Net Report Viewer page, when I select the primary parameter for the first time, nothing is being set for the dependent parameter (no valid values & no default values). While on second selection and going forward everything works normally.

Is this a bug in the ReportViewer? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show your code and any relevant sample data or it will be hard to offer help.

Comment: This is happening with all of the report and not just one report.